# POST data to Next.js page from external application

Tags: post, next.js

I have a java application which sends json data to an API via POST, what i'm trying to do is collect this data from the Next.js application to display and store in a database later. I can't figure out how to fetch this data from the Next app. currently i have the following code in the pages/api/comment and I'm calling the http://localhost:3000/api/comment from the java application

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  if(req.method === 'POST'){
    const comment = req.body.data
    const newCom = {
      id: Date.now(),
      text: comment,
    }
    comments.push(newCom)
    res.status(201).json(newCom)
  }
}
```

Can someone give me some directions please?, Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can't you create this API in your java app and call in Next.js?

Comment: My java app is a maven plugin which collects some metrics data, It should send those to the website whenever the plugin is running. So I'm not sure if this can be done. can it?

Answer (score 0):

Since Next js is working in server less architecture, you need to persist/save data some where like DB on the time of posting data, Then only we an retrieve data by get Api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).